# Can't figure out what's taking up so much memory?

Tags: c#, xna

I've used Pix to see how much memory my vertexbuffers and indices etc take up and they only take up about 80mb, they are only generated once but my app takes up a constant 400mb (never changes).  I've tried CLR profiler 4 but it never loads with my XNA game, I simply get.

"Waiting for application to start common language runtime"

Comment: Without more details, no one will be able to offer an answer. If you can reproduce the problem in a manageable amount of code, post the code and you are more likely to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the profile as an Administrator; Right click run as an Administrator.
Try using the x86 version rather than the 64 bit version.